# DACircularProgress in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone

I am using this open source (https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress) with the following

```
self.largestProgressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.largestProgressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.largestProgressView.thicknessRatio = 1.0f;
```

It works fine on all devices apart from iPhone 5. On iPhone 5 it shows a semi circle shifted to the right of the uiview. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: And potentially an example project showing the problem? (Author here)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue. All I had to do was add Height Constraint for the view.